# Best way to write Group routes with prefix in laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

What is the best and correct way to write the following routing:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']],function (){
    Route::prefix('user')->group(function () {
        //this address shows the login page
        Route::any('login', 'User@login_page');
        //others address that control the login action
        Route::prefix('login')->group(function (){
            Route::get('google', 'User@check_user_login_with_google');
            Route::post('form', 'User@check_user_login_with_form');
            Route::get('google-url', 'User@redirect_to_google_url');
        });
        //these address control the registration actions
        Route::any('register','User@register');
        Route::any('register/check','User@check_user_registration');
    });
});
```

Comment: Not sure I get the question. Is your code not working? Are you asking for an alternative syntax or best practice? Or is it "opinions" of fellow developers you are after (which would actually be against the rules of SO)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it all in one shot:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'user', 'as' => 'user.', 'middleware' => ['web']], function() {
  Route::any('login', 'User@login_page');
  ...
})
```

Comment: missing a `]` to close the array. but i think the ... lets us know this is pseudo code

Comment: Good catch @happymacarts. I have fixed it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use all these in a separate associated array and assign this array to the group here is how to do that .

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'user', 'as' => 'user.', 'middleware' => ['web']], function() {
  Route::any('login', 'User@login_page');
  ...
})
```

Hope this may help you